# Reindex Bins-index DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I would like to add rows and columns with zeros for the bins that do not appear in the index/columns after applying groupby:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

bins = np.arange(-0.1, 2, 0.1)

names = np.random.random_integers(0, 100, 1000)
a = np.random.random(1000)
b = np.random.random(1000)

matrix = pd.DataFrame([names, pd.cut(a, bins), pd.cut(b, bins)]).T
matrix.columns = ['names', 'a', 'b']

matrix = matrix.groupby(['a', 'b']).count()
matrix.reset_index(inplace=True)

matrix = matrix.pivot(index='a', columns='b', values='names').fillna(0)
```

Comment: Your code looks good. What's the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assign the output of your `pandas.cut` method to variables to get access to the [`categories`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Categorical.categories.html#pandas.Categorical.categories) attribute:

```
bins = np.arange(-0.1, 2, 0.1)

names = np.random.random_integers(0, 100, 1000)
a = np.random.random(1000)
b = np.random.random(1000)


##############################
# Use pd.cut like this
a_bins = pd.cut(a, bins)
b_bins = pd.cut(b, bins)
##############################


matrix = pd.DataFrame([names, a_bins, b_bins]).T


matrix.columns = ['names', 'a', 'b']

matrix = matrix.groupby(['a', 'b']).count()
matrix.reset_index(inplace=True)

matrix = matrix.pivot(index='a', columns='b', values='names').fillna(0)

##################################################
# Reindex with this
matrix = matrix.reindex(index=a_bins.categories,
                        columns=b_bins.categories,
                        fill_value=0)
##################################################
```